# Contour Integral help with residue theorem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, integration, contour-integration

$$
K = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{4}+x^{2}+1}dx
$$

I am supposed to use contour integration to solve this, but I can't even determine the singularities.  The denominator doesn't have any that I can see.  From what I understand about contour integration, isn't the solution $ 2\pi i\sum residues $  ? Perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: You're looking for zeros of the denominator, not singularities of the denominator. The zeros of the denominator are the singularities of the integrand. To find them, note that the denominator is biquadratic, so you can solve for $x^2$. Note also that the integrand is symmetric, which allows you to extend the integral over the entire real line.

Answer (score 1):

You can also deal with this integral without using residue theory.

Let

\begin{align*}
I &=\int \frac{1}{1+x^{2}+x^{4}} \ dx  
\\ &= \frac{1}{2} \cdot \int \frac{2}{1+x^{2}+x^{4}} \ dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \cdot \int \frac{(1-x^{2}) + (1+x^{2})}{1+x^{2}+x^{4}} \ dx \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \cdot \int\frac{1-x^{2}}{1+x^{2}+x^{4}} \ dx+ \frac{1}{2} \cdot \int\frac{(1+x^{2})}{1+x^{2}+x^{4}} \ dx
\\ &= I_{1} + I_{2}
\end{align*}

Now to evaluate $I_{1}$ do the following

\begin{align*}
I_{1} &=-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\int \frac{x^{2}-1}{x^{4}+x^{2}+1} \ dx \\
&= -\frac{1}{2}\cdot \int\frac{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}{x^{2}+1+\frac{1}{x^2}} \ dx \\ &=-\frac{1}{2} \cdot \int \frac{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}{\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{2}-1} = -\frac{1}{2} \cdot \int \frac{dt}{t^{2}-1}
\end{align*}

Comment: Too big for a comment, hence I added this!

Comment: Thanks for a solution.  But the problem clearly suggest a contour evaluation solution.

Comment: This is great! :-)

Comment: @joriki: Thanks Joriki! Standard trick though :P

Answer (score 1):

Observe that: $\dfrac{1}{x^4+x^2+1}=\dfrac{x^2-1}{x^6-1}$, now you can use substitution and then integration by parts.

Comment: Thanks, but it has to be solved using the contour method.  The boss man is keen on driving me to drinking here.

Answer (score 1):

Define

$$f(z)=\frac1{z^4+z^2+1}$$

and we have

$$z^4+z^2+1=0\implies z^2_{1,2}=\frac{-1\pm3 i}{2}=e^{\pm\left(\frac{2\pi i}3+2k\pi i\right)}\implies z_k=\pm e^{\pm\frac{\pi i}3\left(1+3k\right)}\;,\;\;k=0,1$$

Thus, our function has two simple poles on the upper half hemisphere (this is all we shall need), with residues

$$I=\text{Res}_{z=e^{\pi i/3}}(z-e^{\pi i/3})f(z)\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\lim_{z\to e^{\pi i/3}}\frac1{4z^3+2z}=\frac1{4e^{\pi i}+2e^{\pi i/3}}=\frac1{-3+\sqrt3\,i}=-\frac14-\frac{\sqrt3}{12}i$$

$$II=\text{Res}_{z=e^{2\pi i/3}}(z-e^{2\pi i/3})f(z)\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\lim_{z\to e^{2\pi i/3}}\frac1{4z^3+2z}=\frac1{4e^{2\pi i}+2e^{2\pi i/3}}=\frac1{3+\sqrt3\,i}=\frac14-\frac{\sqrt3}{12}i$$

Thus, taking the contour:

$$C_R:=[-R,R]\cup\gamma_R:=\{\,z\in\Bbb C\;;\;|z|=R\;,\;\text{Im}(z)\ge 0\,\}\;,\;\;\Bbb R\ni R>>0$$

We get by Cauchy's Integral Theorem

$$\frac\pi{\sqrt3}=2\pi i(-\frac{\sqrt3}6i)=2\pi i(I+II)=\oint\limits_{C_R}f(z)\,dz=\int\limits_{-R}^R\frac{dx}{x^4+x^2+1}+\int\limits_{\gamma_R}f(z)\,dz$$

But by the evaluation theorem we have that

$$\left|\;\int\limits_{\gamma_R}f(z)\,dz\;\right|\le\frac1{R^4-R^2-1}\cdot\pi R\xrightarrow[R\to\infty]{}0$$

So we're left with

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\dfrac{dx}{x^4+x^2+1}=\lim_{R\to\infty}\int\limits_{-R}^R\frac{dx}{x^4+x^2+1}=\frac\pi{\sqrt3}$$

Now use our function is even and divide through by $\,2\,$ to get the wanted integral ...

Answer (score 1):

The singularities of the denominator are in the complex plane:

$$z^4+z^2+1 = 0 \implies z^2 = \frac{-1 \pm i \sqrt{3}}{2}$$

In polar form, $z^2 = e^{i 2 \pi/3}$ or $e^{i 4 \pi/3}$.  Taking square roots, the poles are at $z_1=e^{i \pi/3}$, $z_2=e^{i 2 \pi/3}$, $z_3 = -e^{i \pi/3}$, $z_4=-e^{i 2 \pi/3}$.  Note the particular branch of the square root chosen here.

In this case, the integral stated is equal to $i 2 \pi$ times the sum of the residues inside the integration contour.  What contour?  Well, we had actually considered

$$\oint_C \frac{dz}{z^4+z^2+1}$$

where $C$ is a semicircular contour in the upper-half plane of radius $R$.  In the limit as $R \to \infty$, the integral over the circular arc portion goes to zero.  To see this, parametrize this portion of the contour by $z=R e^{i \phi}$ and get

$$i R \int_0^{\pi} d\phi \, e^{i \phi} \frac{1}{R^4 e^{i 4 \phi}+R^2 e^{i 2 \phi} + 1} \sim \frac{1}{R^3} \quad (R \to \infty)$$

To compute the integral using residues, we must identify which residues are inside the integration contour.  In this case, only $z_1$ and $z_2$ are inside, so we need only consider those.

Residue calculation is simplified by the following fact: when $f(z) = p(z)/q(z)$, the residue of a simple pole of $f$ at $z=z_0$ is $f(z_0)/(q'(z_0)$.  Using this fact, we have the sum of the residues being

$$\frac{1}{4 (e^{i \pi/3})^3 + 2 e^{i \pi/3}} + \frac{1}{4 (e^{i 2 \pi/3})^3 + 2 e^{i 2 \pi/3}}$$

I leave the algebra to the reader; the result I get is

$$K = \frac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{3}}$$